# Git post-checkout hook from in repo

Tags: git, githooks

I am writing a post-checkout hook for git. I want this hook to be included into the repository and run directly after a fresh clone (as it does). However, I cannot add files to the .git/hooks directory in the repository.

Where do add my script in order for git to run it directly after a clone?

**Sidenote:**
I am aware of the security risk this adds, but I am ok with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can add it anywhere in another dir and use `git clone --template=[mydir]` when cloning.
e.g. `mkdir -p ~/my_git/hooks; vi ~/my_git/hooks/post-checkout; git clone --template=~/my_git`

Comment: But that would still require developers to change their habbit, correct? I would like my `post-checkout` script to be run directly after a normal `git clone` command, which it would if the file would exists in the `.git/hooks` folder.

Comment: @PaulPeelen What you're suggesting isn't possible, for security reasons: the cloner has to make a conscious decision to install a hook, lest s/he falls victim of malicious hooks. Git config files don't get cloned for the same reason.

Comment: I was afraid of that. However, that kind of defeats my purpose since I want it to do a `pod update` after cloning, without having to do more stuff as a developer. :(

Comment: @PaulPeelen yes, as workaround you can wrap it in a script

Comment: Yes, but then I would have to run the script manually instead. (or add the `--template` param to the clone call.)